# Create multidimentional array from flat array structure

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [IdProduct] => 1 [ProductName] => p1 [ProductCode] => pc1 [VendorId] => 1 [VendorName] => v1) 
[1] => Array ( [IdProduct] => 2 [ProductName] => p2 [ProductCode] => pc2 [VendorId] => 1 [VendorName] => v1) 
[2] => Array ( [IdProduct] => 3 [ProductName] => p3 [ProductCode] => pc3 [VendorId] => 1 [VendorName] => v1)
[3] => Array ( [IdProduct] => 4 [ProductName] => p4 [ProductCode] => pc4 [VendorId] => 2 [VendorName] => v2)
[4] => Array ( [IdProduct] => 5 [ProductName] => p5 [ProductCode] => pc5 [VendorId] => 2 [VendorName] => v2)
)
```

I am trying to manipulate the array and want an output like below:

```
Array(
['v1']=>array(
    Array ( [IdProduct] => 1 [ProductName] => p1 [ProductCode] => pc1) 
    Array ( [IdProduct] => 2 [ProductName] => p2 [ProductCode] => pc2) 
    Array ( [IdProduct] => 3 [ProductName] => p3 [ProductCode] => pc3)
)
['v2']=>array(
    Array ( [IdProduct] => 4 [ProductName] => p4 [ProductCode] => pc4)
    Array ( [IdProduct] => 5 [ProductName] => p5 [ProductCode] => pc5)
)
)
```

I tried lots of code, but no luck, please help me!

Comment: can you show us your code so far?

Comment: Its easier when you upload the 'lots of code ' you have tried

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `array_reduce`:

```
$array = array_reduce($array, function ($carry, $item) {
    $vendorName = $item['VendorName'];

    unset($item['VendorName'], $item['VendorId']);

    $carry[$vendorName][] = $item;

    return $carry;
}, []);

var_dump($array);
```

Comment: I am getting NULL as output

Comment: You forgot to `return $carry;` at the end of your function

Comment: `$carry[$vendorName][] = $item;` this will work every time, no need to do isset check.

Comment: @MennyMez you're right.. I think in the past it didn't work like that so it's an old way of doing it which I took with me during the time